# How to access Google Cloud Build logs files generated from Firebase function

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, npm, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

My Google Build script is stuck in his step with it build the server of Angular universal project. I am trying to access the logs maybe it helps to fix the problem.

Edit #1

> It is an Angular project and this build is Angular universal build on Firebase functions

```
Starting Step #6
Step #6: Already have image: node:12.3
Step #6: 
Step #6: > supportfinity@0.0.0 stage-server /workspace
Step #6: > node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng run sf-mini:server:stage
Step #6: 
Step #6: Compiling angular2-query-builder : main as umd
Step #6: Killed
Step #6: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
Step #6: npm ERR! errno 137
Step #6: npm ERR! supportfinity@0.0.0 stage-server: `node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng run sf-mini:server:stage`
Step #6: npm ERR! Exit status 137
Step #6: npm ERR! 
Step #6: npm ERR! Failed at the supportfinity@0.0.0 stage-server script.
Step #6: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
Step #6: 
Step #6: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Step #6: npm ERR!     /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2020-10-05T12_48_55_502Z-debug.log
Finished Step #6
```

How to access the logs above.

Also here is the build yaml:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'build', '-t' , 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase' , './dockerfiles/firebase']
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase'
  args: [ 'use', '$_PROJECT_NAME','--token', '${_FIREBASE_TOKEN}']
- name: 'node:12.3'
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install']
- name: 'node:12.3'
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install','--prefix','functions']
- name: 'node:12.3'
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['link']
- name: 'node:12.3'
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['run-script','stage-browser']
- name: 'node:12.3'
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['run-script','--debug','build-server'] <== this one which cause problem
- name: 'node:12.3'
  entrypoint: npm
  dir:  'functions'
  args: ['run-script','copyAndRename']
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase'
  args: [ 'deploy','--debug', '--token', '${_FIREBASE_TOKEN}']
timeout: 2000s
```

build command from package.json

```
    "build-server": "node --max_old_space_size=16384 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng run sf-mini:server:production",
    "stage-browser": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --configuration=stage --aot --vendor-chunk --common-chunk --delete-output-path",
```

Comment: You will not be able to access this logs since this one is VM that is running the cloud build step, nevertheless, are you using  App Engine Standard? If so you can use the [local Emulator](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server) in order to troubleshot your app. Also, you can add the [verbosity flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference) to get more information about the error.

Comment: I agree with the first comment but the local emulator is only for Python apps, This error is  Node related.

Answer (score -1):

It could be a memory problem. There are several GitHub [[1]](https://github.com/hackmdio/codimd/issues/1254)
[[2]](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4008) issues that that has error code 137 and they're able to fix the problem by increasing their RAM.

**EDIT:**
As mentioned in the comment, you won't be able to access `/builder` logs because a separate [VM](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#machinetype) runs the build steps.

However, this may help you understand what's causing the problem. The valid maximum memory value in Firebase Functions is [2GB](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation) but you are increasing your memory to 16GB *(build)* and 8GB *(stage)* using `--max_old_space_size`. This could help explain why you're getting that out of memory code.